# JQuery mobile changes html code

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'd like use jqm to detect swipe, but if I add that to my code I see HTML code changed!!

For example, input radio elements are wrapped by

<div class=" ui-radio">    </div>

Can I inhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution:

add this piece of script before you load the jQuery mobile library:

> <script type="text/javascript">$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){$.extend(  $.mobile , {autoInitializePage: false})});</script>

This prevents jquery mobile from initializing the page and touching the DOM, thus leaving your layout alone (thanks to eivers88)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `data-role="none"` to the element should stop jQuery Mobile from adding those additional classes.

Source: [jQuery Mobile Demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html)

Comment: Yes, it works for input elements. But I have others problems, for example with links. My aim is to have jqm swipe detection, without the html code transformation that jqm seems operate by default